# How to reformat react calendar date

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

So I am currently creating a website for receptionists and would like the relevant appointments to appear when a date is clicked on react calendar.

Currently, when I console.log the clicked date it appears in the following format:
Tue Jun 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)

I would like it to appear instead as:
2022-06-07

This is so that it is coherent with my database.

My code is as follows:

```
const Calendar = () => {

const CalendarChange = () => {
    console.log("hi");
};

    
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const onDateChange = (newDate) => {
    // let NewDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
    setDate(newDate);

    console.log(newDate);
}

const locale = 'fr-CA';

return (
    <>
       <CalendarContainer>
             <Calendarcom calendarType='US' format="dd-MM-yyyy" className='react-calendar' 
              onChange={onDateChange}           
              value={date} />
         </CalendarContainer>
    </>
 
    );
};

export default Calendar;
```

Comment: Doens't the line that is commented out sort of do that for you?

Comment: When I used the line that was commented, it only worked on a few dates and then stopped working all together on some dates.

Comment: hmm.. could you give an example of a date that didn't work?

Comment: So I just checked again, and the new date only shows if you click twice.

Comment: What if you do it manually? ```date => "${date.getYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}"```

Comment: If I added that code, where would I place it, because currently it's not working but I think my placement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone's help!

I managed to get it working with the following code:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [formatDate, setFormatDate] = useState();

//    console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
const onDateChange = (newDate) => {

    setDate(newDate);
  
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(date);
  setFormatDate(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
  console.log(formatDate);
}, [date, onDateChange])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).